# Why does a Solandra 2 node cluster perform indexing worse than a single node cluster?

Tags: solrj, solandra

In indexing tests using Solrj, 2 Solandra nodes are performing worse than 1.

- Each node is -Xms1G -Xmx12G
- Single index; Index is ~10M docs; each doc is ~4KB in size with a unique id.  I built up the index to about 6M on a single node, then added a new node to the ring and used "move" to assign new tokens to balance.
- Using all Solandra default configs - for example:  solandra.maximum.docs.per.shard = 1048576, solandra.index.id.reserve.size = 16384, solandra.shards.at.once = 4
- Nodetool ring shows:node1  Up  Normal  35.11 GB  50.00%  0, node2  Up  Normal  54.5 GB   50.00%  85070591730234615865843651857942052864
- Indexing performance:
  single node:  166 docs/s
  2 nodes(sending to single node):  111 docs/s
  2 nodes (sending to both in parallel):  55 docs/s (see note below)

(note) I was sending batches of 100K (a batch is building up a list of SolrInputDocuments + commit on whole list), and when I switched to batches of 10K, there was some performance improvement to 98 docs/s

Some questions:

- In general, for both indexing & searching, how can I get Solandra to perform better with more than 1 node?
- Why does indexing performance degrade with 2 nodes versus 1?  When should I expect a performance upgrade?
- What is the recommended way to index documents with Solandra- sending to a single node in the ring or to multiple nodes?
- What is the recommended way to query with Solandra- sending query requests to a single node or multiple nodes?
- Send all query requests to a single node in a 2 node cluster performs roughly the same as a single node cluster - any ideas why?